# Vertical Alignment in table Latex

Tags: vertical-alignment

I would like to make "Dataset" and the entries of the table centered vertically of the following table:

Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,graphicx}
    \usepackage{multirow} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Variable}  \\
            \cline{2-3}  & $T=50$, Levels  &  $T=50$, Logs \\[5pt]
            \cline{2-3} &  $T=300$, Levels  &  $T=300$, Logs \\[5pt]
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{Simulaion Settings}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{table}
        \centering
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
            \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Variable}  \\
            \cline{2-3}  & $T=50$, Levels  &  $T=50$, Logs \\
            \cline{2-3} &  $T=300$, Levels  &  $T=300$, Logs \\
        \end{tabular} 
        \caption{Simulaion Settings}
    \end{table}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,graphicx}
    \usepackage{multirow}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}   %% <--- this added
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
            \multirow{3}[6]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Variable}  \\
            \cline{2-3}  & $T=50$, Levels  &  $T=50$, Logs \\[5pt]
            \cline{2-3} &  $T=300$, Levels  &  $T=300$, Logs \\[5pt]
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Simulaion Settings}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

I have used the optional argument of `\multirow` to lower the content.

[image]